# whether Y(employees injured) variation is due to X1(job function) or X2(population)

Tags: self-study, inference

Here is the actual question-
There are 1000 employees in a firm, and the firm has four departments namely D1, D2, D3 and D4 with 100, 200, 300, 400 employees respectively.
Now, each employee is explained about what constitutes an injury(for this experiment). Then, each employee is asked whether they were injured in last year. Their responses grouped according to the departments they are in -
D1= 10, D2= 20, D3= 30, D4=40,

It is to be noted that each department has different job function like for example D1 is HR department, and D4 is machining department.

Now, we have to determine whether no. of employees injured in each department (variation) is due to- Job function of the departments OR Population of the department?

PS- I'm new to statistics, so this question can be very easy or trivial, it would definitely help me a lot if any could guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

---

This has been my thought process-
Y= No. of employees injured last year.
X1= Population (of employees) in department
X2= Job function of the department

both Y and X1 are numerical variables and X2 is categorical.
If we find correlation coefficient of Y with X1 and Y with X2, it will be same. So we have to think of other way.
Also, I think in this case there is collinearity between X1 and X2, which may cause one of the variable to be redundant or rather both X1 and X2 imply same thing.

So, I'm kind of stuck with here. Any help regarding this question would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just basic mathematics : in each department, exactly 10% of the employees were injured last year. So this has nothing to do with their job function.

If this percentage had varied significantly between the departments, then this would be due to job function.

Comment: That's a good observation about the constant injury rate. I was thinking, though, that this question could be answered (in the negative) even without looking at the numbers. Suppose (hypothetically) the injury rates did vary.  What would justify the conclusion that *job function* is the cause?  Maybe the departments are housed in different areas and location is the cause, for instance.  Thus, although department could be *associated* with injury rates, we still could not justify any causal--"due to"--conclusions based on such data.

Comment: cloud Skywalker- Thanks for reply, Actually, it was an interview question and interviewer specifically said that each job func. has different STRESS level(RISK was my interpretation) with examples like Machining and HR department.
However, I duly concur with your explanation but I think the answer should be somewhat "less straightforward", and probably require some concepts of statistics.It may be the case that interviewer might have thought of this question instantaneously, which can explains such loose definition of question.